# NFC applications from market override "Complete action using" dialog entries

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

I have installed [NXP TagWriter](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nxp.nfc.tagwriter) and [NFC TagInfo](https://market.android.com/details?id=at.mroland.android.apps.nfctaginfo) on Nexus S, the same device used for my NFC application development. The problem is my application is not shown in the "Complete action using" dialog after Tag is read, only both installed from market are. After debugging it for a while, I have tried using [demo application](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NFCDemo/) and the result was the same. What am I missing here? Do applications have to be installed from the market in order to have intent filters parsed properly?

**Update**

My intent-filter was simply

```
<intent-filter>
  <action   android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

I have tried adding others as specified in [manual](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html), one by one as well as all together without success. Could it have something to do with mime type?

When NFC tag is read, only these two lines are related to the action and nothing else.

```
INFO/ActivityManager(111): Starting: Intent { act=android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.nxp.nfc.tagwriter/.activities.DashboardActivity (has extras) } from pid 197
INFO/ActivityManager(111): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.nxp.nfc.tagwriter/.activities.ConfirmLicenseActivity } from pid 6250
```

Seeing `android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED` is triggered, I have added following intent-filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action   android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>

<meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
           android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
```

And `res/xml/nfc_tech_filter.xml` contains

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

Comment: sounds unlikly, but ididn't undersand, if you have your application installed without the other two u mentioned does your IntentFilter works ?

Comment: Correct, if my and NFCDemo are installed, dialog with My, NFCDemo and Tags is shown, if NXP TagWriter or NFC TagInfo are installed, they are run right away, not even pre-installed Tags is shown. If both from market are installed, they are both listed as an option, Tags is however not.

Comment: this is indeed weired, there should be no difference for installng apps from the market to installing apps from the adb or sdcard.
regarding the intent filter, what is the exact intnet you want to capture / it'e enoug that a mime type is different and tagWriter has it but u don't for you to be filtered out, android gives u the BEST matches, could it be that u are missing a small pirece for the ilter to join the intnet party?

Comment: TAG_DISCOVERED for now, I have tried adding all three without success, I have even added [meta-data](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/index.html#manifest) and still nothing. Since the tags are empty, there is no mime type specified in the manifest file. The interesting thing is that default Tags application, which is part of firmware, is not shown either.

Comment: please post the intent-filter. I'd also say TAG_DISCOVERED should make you app show up. In case you'd like to make sure the intent chooser is not shown, btw, and you app launches directly, create a NDEF MIME tag with a mime type that you filter relates to your activity. The filter process begins with ndef mime messages, then goes on to filter based on tech, finally TAG_DISCOVERED.

Comment: I have updated question with additional information on intent-filter.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason TAG_DISCOVERED does not pop up your app is because it is the fall-back option: only when no matches for the NDEF_DISCOVERED and TECH_DISCOVERED intents can be found, TAG_DISCOVERED will be dispatched.

Since the NXP apps register for TECH_DISCOVERED, they will be preferred over your app. Your solution to include a TECH_DISCOVERED filter is correct, but the way you do it is wrong. The technologies in a "tech-list" block are AND-ed together; so in your example, this means that the filter will only match tags that have NfcA AND NfcB AND MifareClassic. Since NfcA and NfcB are very different technologies that don't go together, this filter will never match.

What you really want is an OR of all the different technologies. To do that, simply write multiple  blocks containing only one technology:

```
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
</tech-list>
```

This will match NfcA OR NfcB. Of course, you should make your filter as accurate as possible, to prevent the application list from clobbering up. If you're only interested in NfcA tags, don't claim the others.

Comment: Thank you, I have missed AND/OR part in documentation. However, if I try specifying them separately or even just the ones our tags support, the outcome is still the same. It is really confusing :)

Comment: That's weird, can you run `adb logcat -s RegisteredComponentCache:*` and reinstall your package? After a few seconds you should see some logging coming by, indicating which activity has registered for which technology.

Comment: I feel stupid now :) The logs have shown only `com.nxp.nfc.tagwriter.activities.DashboardActivity` for all tech types, after going through manifest yet again, I spotted a typo. `intent-filter` was outside of activity and was therefore not registered. However, had you not supplied valid answer, I'd still not see it. One huge thanks to you :)

Comment: Martijn your explanation is awesome! You saved my 10 hours today!

Comment: So easy to ignore AND and OR concept while reading. I spent a one full day to resolve this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to have found this after a crawling through stackoverflow for a couple of hours!

Answer (score 0):

Your tech list should consist of the combination of technologies you think your card supports. For example, if the card you want to read has NfcA, NfcB and MifareClassic then your techlist should have:

```
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech>
</tech-list>
```

You can have more than one tech-list tags in your resources. Only if a tag matches one of the tech-lists in your resources will your app be detected.

Comment: Shouldn't above `tech-list` match those tags? Or are there several needed?

Comment: w.r.t above tech list, a card will be detected only when it detects NfcA, NfcB and MifareClassic. It can not be either or.