# how to scan an unformatted NFC tag

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, intentfilter

I've an app that scans NFC tags to get information from the payload and then sends that info to a server via web service. It works fine. The tags are Mifare. The mobile part of the system before i joined the company was written in J2me for nokia c700. I've re-written the system in Android. The Android app can get the tag ID and read the payload. If there is no payload then it just reads the tag ID, which is fine.

The problem is when i scan a tag that has not been formatted then i can't get the tagID. The old system on the nokias could read a tagID from an **unformatted** tag. How can i do this in Android? Why does the tag have to be formatted?

Thanks in advance.

[edit]

```
if( intentAction.equalsIgnoreCase(NFC_ACTION)){

             nfcScanTimeFromDB = null;

            cursor = nfcscannerapplication.loginValidate.getLastTagFromTransations();

            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                if (cursor.moveToLast()) {

                    _tagScanTime = cursor.getLong(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_TAG_SCAN_TIME));

                    nfcScanTimeFromDB = new DateTime(_tagScanTime);

                }
            }

            if(cursor.getCount() == 0){
                //DB must be empty
                Log.e(TAG, "just scanned an nfc tag and DB must be empty");
                Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

                tagId = bytesToHexString(tag.getId());
                Log.e(TAG, "tagId immediately after scanning nfc tag = " + tagId);

                if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {

                    Log.e(TAG, "NFC Tag scanned");

                    // get the messages from the intent
                    Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent
                            .getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
                    if (rawMsgs != null) {
                        msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
                        for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                            msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "ndef not discovered!!!!!!");
                }

                 Cursor c = nfcscannerapplication.loginValidate.queryAllFromCarer();

                  if(c.getCount() == 0){

                      Toast.makeText(this, "Please login before signing in",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      Intent intent = new Intent(NfcscannerActivity.this, EntryActivity.class);
                      startActivity(intent);
                  }else{
                      c.moveToLast();
                      tagPerson = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_CARER_ID));
                  }




                // process the msgs array
                for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {

                    NdefRecord[] records = msgs[i].getRecords();
                    Log.e(TAG, "ndefrecord has a length of " + records.length);

                    tr = parse(records[i]);
                    payload = tr.getText();

                    Log.e(TAG, "TextRecord.text = " + tr.getText());


                }

                if(payload.length() == 0){

                    tagType = "1";
                    tagCompany = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_COMP_ID));
                    tagPerson = tagId;//c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_CARER_ID));
                    tagUserName = tagId;
                    tagLatitude = "0.0000000";
                    tagLongitude = "0.0000000"; 

                    if(rotasOnly.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
                         processinfo();
                    }
                }else{

                // /////////////////////////////////////////////////// split the payload
                // using delimiter. assign value at position[0] to tagType
                String[] splitPayload = payload.split(",");



                tagType = splitPayload[0];
                //tagCompany = splitPayload[1];


                c.moveToLast();
                tagCompany = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_COMP_ID));


                if(splitPayload[2].length() == 0 || splitPayload[2] == null || splitPayload[2].trim().equalsIgnoreCase("0")){

                    tagPerson = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_CARER_ID));

                }else{

                tagPerson = splitPayload[2];

                }

                tagUserName = splitPayload[3];
                tagLatitude = "0.0000000";
                tagLongitude = "0.0000000"; 

                if(rotasOnly.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
                     processinfo();

                }else{
                    Log.e(TAG, "cant process tag because of company option 160 rotas only");
                }

                }   

            }else{



            //DB not empty///////////////////

            DateTime nfcScanTimeMinustagTouchInterval = new DateTime();
            nfcScanTimeMinustagTouchInterval.minusMinutes(Integer.parseInt(tagTouchInterval));





//          AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
//          // For example to set the volume of played media to maximum.
//          audioManager.setStreamVolume (AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 
//                        audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC),0);
//          MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.meep2); 
//          mediaPlayer.start();
            //mediaPlayer.release();
            //mediaPlayer = null; 


        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

        tagId = bytesToHexString(tag.getId());
        Log.e(TAG, "tagId immediately after scanning nfc tag = " + tagId);

        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {

            Log.e(TAG, "NFC Tag scanned");

            // get the messages from the intent
            Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent
                    .getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
            if (rawMsgs != null) {
                msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "ndef not discovered!!!!!!");
        }

         Cursor c = nfcscannerapplication.loginValidate.queryAllFromCarer();

          if(c.getCount() == 0){

              Toast.makeText(this, "Please login before signing in",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              Intent intent = new Intent(NfcscannerActivity.this, EntryActivity.class);
              startActivity(intent);
          }else{
              c.moveToLast();
              tagPerson = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_CARER_ID));
          }




        // process the msgs array
        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {

            NdefRecord[] records = msgs[i].getRecords();
            Log.e(TAG, "ndefrecord has a length of " + records.length);

            tr = parse(records[i]);
            payload = tr.getText();

            Log.e(TAG, "TextRecord.text = " + tr.getText());
            Log.e(TAG, "payload len = " + payload.length() + " so must be a blank formatted tag!");


        }

        if(payload.length() == 0){

            tagType = "1";
            tagCompany = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_COMP_ID));
            tagPerson = tagId;//c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_CARER_ID));
            tagUserName = tagId;
            tagLatitude = "0.0000000";
            tagLongitude = "0.0000000"; 

            if(rotasOnly.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
                 processinfo();
            }
        }else{


        // /////////////////////////////////////////////////// split the payload
        // using delimiter. assign value at position[0] to tagType
        String[] splitPayload = payload.split(",");



        tagType = splitPayload[0];
        //tagCompany = splitPayload[1];
        tagCompany = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_COMP_ID));

        if(splitPayload[2].length() == 0 || splitPayload[2] == null || splitPayload[2].trim().equalsIgnoreCase("0")){

            tagPerson = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_CARER_ID));

        }else{

        tagPerson = splitPayload[2];

        }

        tagUserName = splitPayload[3];
        tagLatitude = "0.0000000";
        tagLongitude = "0.0000000"; 

        if(rotasOnly.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
             processinfo();
        }else{
            Log.e(TAG, "cant process tag because of company option 160 rotas only");
        }


        }   

            }//finished processing tag with a NONE empty DB




        }
```

[edit2]

```
if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
                  Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
                  byte[] tagIdbyteArray = tag.getId();
                  Log.e(TAG, "unformatted tag found with a tagID of " + tagIdbyteArray);
                }
```

[edit3]

```
<activity
            android:name=".NfcscannerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.carefreegroup.QRCODE_ACTION" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
            </intent-filter> 

            <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                       android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />

        </activity>
```

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
  <tech-list>
      <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
  </tech-list>
</resources>
```

.

```
if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
                  Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
                  byte[] tagIdbyteArray = tag.getId();
                  Log.e(TAG, "unformatted tag found with a tagID of " + tagIdbyteArray);
                }
```

[edit 4]

```
01-21 09:27:35.180: D/NativeNfcTag(512): Connect Failed - status = 146
01-21 09:27:35.180: E/NFC JNI(512): doDisconnect() - Target already disconnected
```

[edit5]

```
01-21 10:07:25.420: E/NfcService(512): No tag fallback activity found for Intent { act=android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED (has extras) }
```

[edit6]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
  <tech-list>

    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
  </tech-list>
</resources>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "formatted"?

Comment: It should work and works fine with other apps. Can you include the code?

Comment: @NFCguy Hi, If I scan a tag that is straight off the roll then the app is not capturing the tag ID. For my app to get the tag ID i must firstly write to the tag's payload with a seperate tag writer/reader. i can leave the payload blank if i want, but the tag writer must alter the tag's format to NDEF. My app captures tags that are in NDEF. so i can only presume that the tags don't come in NDEF format, but it's funny how the old nokia c700 in j2me can do this

Comment: @kichik hi i've updated the post to include the nfc part of my app. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the MIFARE Classic tags are not formatted to contain NDEF, you can receive an intent for them (and get the ID) as follows (from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#tech-disc)):

Add to you manifest for the activity that needs to receive the intents:

```
<activity>
  ...
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>

  <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
    android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
  ...
</activity>
```

Create a new file `<project-root>/res/xml/nfc_tech_filter.xml` containing:

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
  <tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech>
  </tech-list>
  <tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
  </tech-list>
</resources>
```

In your activity, at some suiutable place, add:

```
if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
  Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
  byte[] tagId = tag.getId();
}
```

Comment: hey thanks alot. i did read the documentation, but was filtering for android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED and tag_discovered as because when i scanned an unformatted tag eclipse logged out no fallback tag etc. thanks again i'll give this a try.

Comment: i've just edited the post again [edit2]. I've added that code to my activity and the done the other amendments to the manifest and res/xml folder, but it is not logging anything out/capturing the unformatted tag. any ideas?

Comment: There was a mistake in the formatting of my answer: the intent filter for TECH_DISCOVERED was not displayed for some reason. Did you add that already yourself?

Comment: hi yes i looked at the documentation and worked it out. it still didn't work so i added the full tech list, but still no joy. i've scanned a formatted tag with another tag reader and it says that it's an NFC Forum type 2 tag if that makes adifference? i've posted all the codes in edit3 thanks

Comment: Oops, I forgot `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>` in the intent filter (the docs also don't show it, but it is necessary). Type 2 Tag means that the unformatted tag is a MIFARE Ultralight (not Classic), so I added that also in the XML tech list.

Comment: Hi no i'm afraid it has made no difference, nothing is getting logged out about the tag.

Comment: i've done some more testing and looked at the logcat with no filters on. I've post the logcat after a scan of an unformatted tag(edit4). It states status 146 and that Target already disconnected?

Comment: also i've scanned the tag again and edit4 problems are no longer there but now instead edit5 is logged out.

Comment: [solved] I search for the error in edit5 and came across this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511343/nfc-applications-from-market-override-complete-action-using-dialog-entries It has something to do with and/or in the tech-list. so i just included one tech ultralight and it works fine now. thanks